# Windows phone: how can i retrieve data from tasks in outlook?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, outlook, windows-phone-8

I want to retrieve data from tasks in outlook, including it's fields priority, Important and due date in windows phone 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such task available in wp8 for retrieving all such specific information from outlook. Please use this link to get basic idea about available launchers and choosers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394029(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: How can I retrieve anything from outlook in wp8?

Comment: I didn't find any API that works as u mentioned. I am nor 100 % confident to say "this is not possible" But as per my findings there is no alternatives are available to achieve you requirement

Comment: The Calendar in wp8 retrieves data from outlook, I want to do the same -only not with events- tasks to add them to a to-do list.

I totally understand what you are saying, thank you

Comment: http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2012/11/08/building-for-windows-phone-8-dont-create-a-calendar-api-access-to-key-functions-is-a-no-go/

Comment: If you are comfortable with the answer provided by rakesh, mark it as answer.